# DefaultButton on Panels not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have three panels on my user settings page: View Settings, Edit Settings, and Update Password.

Update Password panel is always displayed below view settings or edit settings panel.

I have defaultbuttons set for each panel, yet when I'm within a textbox in the updatepassword panel and hit enter, it is clicking on either Edit Settings (on the view settings page) or Save (on the Edit Settings page).

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlViewSettings" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnEditSettingsViewPanel">
...conent...
<center><asp:Button ID="btnEditSettingsViewPanel" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="Edit Settings"  /></center>                           
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlEditSettings" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSaveSettings">
...content...
<center><asp:Button ID="btnSaveSettings" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="Save"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnReturnToSettingsEditPanel" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="Return to Profile"  />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlUpdatePassword" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnUpdatePassword">
...content...
<center><asp:Button ID="btnUpdatePassword" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="Update Password"/></center>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Is one the the panels inside a master page?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar All of the panels are within Settings.aspx

Comment: Do you have js logic on the button clicks? Or are you using server side only pnl.OnClick for all the panels on the Page_Load event?

Comment: No js logic. The issue is when I'm in one of the textboxes in the UpdatePassword panel and hit the enter key, it triggers the Edit Settings or Save button instead of the Update Password button.

Comment: Here is what the panels look like if it helps: http://imgur.com/a/zse1w

Comment: It can be helpful if you update the question with some more code. The buttons Click events registration and all the relevant Panel/Button/Textboxes/etc